# Gitkraken commit issues

Tags: git, gitkraken

I have 3 folders:

```
  Master on Local1 (PC 1)
  Master on Remote (Github)  
  Master on Local2 (another PC)
```

I try to push on Master Remote using GitKraken from Local1.
GitKraken said the push is successful.
But, I could not see on Remote.

But; if I push using Master local2, I could see the commit on Remote.

[image]

How to push correctly using local1 ?

Comment: GitKraken sometimes says it pushed successfully although it did not. I encountered this when a push was rejected on remote by a pre-receive hook.

Comment: yes, there are quite some bugs in GiKraken.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue like this:

open a CMD window and CD to inside your GIT repo.
Type: git push
   the response shows : git push a  b

Copy this statement git push  a b

..and you'll see what GIT is actually pushing without Gitkraken.

(Maybe first stop the Gitkraken program)

ps: There are still BIG mistakes in gitkraken, be aware not to loose files, branches etc. It can even destroy a branch in github without touching anything when you have difficult merge conflicts. You should send your buglist to gitkraken, they will also help you very well.